# Assigning the :hint value in Formtastic's :Range/Slider option to be values in the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm currently attempting to assign the value of the :hint property of formtastic to the options that I've supplied it in the array when using the :range option. So as you drag the slider the numbers, in this case 1-5 are displayed on screen via the :hint. Is this possible? I'd appreciate any help and have included some basic sample code below to illustrate my point.

I'm using rails 3.1 and formtastic 2.0.0 rc5

```
<%= semantic_form_for @ratings do |form| %>
 <%= form.inputs do %>
  <%= form.input :enjoyment, :as => :range, :collection => [1,2,3,4,5], :default => 3, :hint => '<%= enjoyment.value.here %>' %> 
 <% end %>

<%= form.buttons do %>
 <%= form.commit_button %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks